# values in Dictionary not ordered

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm getting a random ordered dict every time I compile, even using ordered dict. Im using dictionary to represent trees so its important to respect the order of the nodes. I had tried with python 3.6 and 3.7

```
class NP: #NounPhrase
 def __init__(self, anchor = None, number = None):
  self.anchor = anchor
  self.number = number

class VP: #VerbPhrase
 def __init__(self, anchor = None , person = None, tense = None):
  self.person = person
  self.tense = tense
  self.anchor = anchor

class Tree:  
 def __init__(self, tree, sust = None, insert = None, anchor = None, terminal = None):
  self.tree = tree
  self.sust = sust
  self.insert = insert    
  self.root = self.getRoot()

 def getRoot(self):
  return list(self.tree.keys())[0]

class TreeForest:
 def makeIntransitiveVerb(text):    
  vp = VP(text)
  return Tree( OrderedDict({ VP:{ NP , vp }}) )


verb = TreeForest.makeIntransitiveVerb("showed up")
print(verb.tree)
```

Expected result:

```
{< class '__main__.VP' > : { < class '__main__.NP' > , < __main__.VP object at 0x7f4b81fd8b90>}}
```

Actual results:

```
{< class '__main__.VP' >: {< __main__.VP object at 0x7f4b81fd8b90 >, < class '__main__.NP' >}})
```

Or

```
{< class '__main__.VP' >: { < class '__main__.NP' > , < __main__.VP object at 0x7f4b81fd8b90>}}
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't order so that's expected. And your `OrderedDict` is being constructed using a dictionary object that's already been created, and hence is no longer ordered.

Comment: Really? I thought dictionaries respected the insertion order in python 3.7 :/

Comment: Your values are actually sets (with similar syntax, just without `:`). They are ways unordered.

Comment: You are right, I didnt knew a key should have just one value, so this value is a set. I'm not sure if I will have to change the structure to nested lists :/